# Deux questions sur "Les non-vaccinés, j’ai très envie de les emmerder."

Tags: grammaire, sens, usage, registre, politique

> [Les non-vaccinés, j’ai très envie de les emmerder](https://www.franceinter.fr/politique/les-non-vaccines-j-ai-tres-envie-de-les-emmerder-les-propos-d-emmanuel-macron-detonent-dans-l-opposition). (Président Macron)

J'ai deux questions sur cette tournure :

1. Comment s'appelle ce phénomène grammatical ? Au lieu de "J’ai très envie d'emmerder les non-vaccinés, le président a mis le complément en tête de sa phrase. Est-ce une mise en apposition ?
2. Quand j'ai appris le français, le prof m'a dit de n'utiliser le verbe "emmerder" que dans un contexte informel. Le [dictionnaire](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/emmerder) Collins confirme. Quand peut-on utiliser le verbe "emmerder" dans un contexte formel ?

Comment: 2. En théorie jamais. Mais chacun a ses critères, ça fait rigoler certains, ça choque d'autres. Pas important. Je ne pense pas qu'il soit prévu de faire de sondage ici ? Lire la presse aujourd'hui te donnera déjà un bon aperçu.

Comment: I agree with President Macron that the 'non-vaccinEs' deserve whatever they end up getting. Maybe he was about to say "Les non-vaccinEs, je vous emmerde!" and thought better of it after starting his sentence.

Comment: Histoire d'élargir l'horizon. [Insultes, punchlines, vulgarités : les sorties verbales des présidents de la République](https://www.elle.fr/Societe/L-actu-en-images/Insultes-punchlines-vulgarites-les-sorties-verbales-des-presidents-de-la-Republique).

Comment: Vu hier soir dans l'émission "Quotidien": des membres du parti LREM qui défendent les propos de Macron en argumentant qu'il "parle tout simplement comme tous les Français", et les membres de tous partis de l'opposition dénoncant un langage inapproprié. Cela montre combien ce mot "emmerder" est inhabituel dans ce contexte et provoque la polémique.

Comment: Un excellent article sur les différentes traductions de cette phrase par la presse internationale: https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2022/01/06/merde-emmerder-les-emmerde/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Réponse à l a question « 1 ». Il s'agit d'une *dislocation à gauche*.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dislocation_%C3%A0_gauche))
>
> **dislocation à gauche** \dis.lɔ.ka.sjɔ̃ a ɡoʃ\ féminin
> (Grammaire) Déplacement d’un syntagme au tête de la phrase, négligeant la structure ordinaire définie par le verbe, pour une thématisation ou pour un contraste comme les syntagmes en lettres grasses dans les phrases suivantes en français parlé
> ♦  a. Moi, je trouve ce film très amusant.
> ♦ b. Ce film, je le trouve très amusant.
> ♦  c. Moi, ce film, je le trouve très amusant.